# Hadoop NFS gateway - mount failed: No such file or directory

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs

I'm trying to mount my HDFS using the NFS gateway as it is documented here:
http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsNfsGateway.html

Unfortunately, following the documentation step by step does not work for me (Hadoop 2.7.1 on CentOS 6.6). When executing the mount command I receive the following error message:

> [root@server1 ~]# mount -t nfs -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock,noacl,sync
>   server1:/ /hdfsmount/ mount.nfs: mounting server1:/ failed, reason
>   given by server: No such file or directory

I created the folder hdfsmount so that I can say it definitely exists. My questions are now:

- Did anyone faced the same issue as I do?
- Do I have to configure the NFS server before I start following the steps in the documentation (e.g. I read about editing /etc/exports).

Any help is highly apreciated!

Comment: where did you find the nfs log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem deep in the logs. When executing the command (see below) to start the nfs3 component of HDFS, the executing user needs permissions to delete `/tmp/.hdfs-nfs` which is configured as `nfs.dump.dir` in `core-site.xml`.

If the permissions are not set, you'll receive a log message like:

> 15/08/12 01:19:56 WARN fs.FileUtil: Failed to delete file or dir
>   [/tmp/.hdfs-nfs]: it still exists. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.io.IOException: Cannot remove current dump directory:
>   /tmp/.hdfs-nfs

Another option is to simply start the nfs component as root.

> [root]> /usr/local/hadoop/sbin/hadoop-daemon.sh --script /usr/local/hadoop/bin/hdfs start nfs3